# React DispatchEvent Not Triggering Keydown

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, dom-events, keyboard-events

I am new to React & Nextjs and working on a flyout menu can get the menu to display onMouseEnter, but in the OnMouseLeave Event for the PopOver panel, the DispatchEvent for the Escape Key does not look like it is being triggered. When I hot the Escape key, the menu closes, but cannot get it to work with the DispatchEvent.

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Here is the code.

**Definition:**

```
const dropdownRef = useRef(null);
```

**Function**

```
const closeMenu = () => {
    console.log("In Close Menu - dropdownref= " + dropdownRef);
    
    dropdownRef &&
    dropdownRef.current?.dispatchEvent(
      new KeyboardEvent("keydown", {
        key: "Escape",
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
      })
    );
```

**Usage**

```
<Popover.Panel
    ref={dropdownRef}
    onMouseLeave={() => useHover && onMouseLeave(open, "1")}
    className="absolute z-10 w-screen max-w-sm px-4 mt-3 transform -translate-x-1/2 left- 
    1/2 sm:px-0 lg:max-w-3xl">
```

Comment: Where does `Popover.Panel` come from?

Comment: headlessui/react

Comment: Also, here is a code pen.  When you hover over the button, you will see the menu open... however, onMouseLeave, nothing happens ...